# Que estoy haciendo mal en este ejercicio?

Tags: javascript, array

quiero saber que estoy haciendo mal en este ejercicio, ya que he probado varias maneras y siempre da error. Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ok, acá va el código escrito, perdón por ese detalle! Claro, el tema es que si bien me dan correcto algunos resultados, hay otros que no me salen bien, que son los que aparecen en rojo.

```
function seAbre(ingresos, alumnnos) {
  var abre = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ingresos[i].length; i++) {
    var alumnosTemprano = 0; 
    for (var j = 0; j < ingresos[i].length; j++) {
      if (ingresos[i][j] <= 0) {
        alumnosTemprano++
      }
    } 

    if (alumnosTemprano >= alumnos) {
      abre.push(true)
    } else {
      abre.push(false)
    }
  }
  return abre;
}

function aperturas(array, alumnos) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var alumnosLlegada = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] <=0) {
        alumnosLlegada++
      }
    }
    if (alumnosLlegada >= alumnos) {
      resultado.push(true)
    } else {
      resultado.push(false)
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido @Emi_E, deberías incluir tu código como texto en lugar de en una imagen, así a la gente le resultará más fácil copiarlo y probarlo para poder ayudarte. También estaría bien que detallaras cual es el problema: ¿se produce un error?, ¿devuelve un resultado diferente al esperado?

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta para incluir el código y poder ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ese detalle! no lo había tenido en cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Asier! Al volver a leer la consigna varias veces y más lentamente comprendí lo que vos decías de los arrays (que no tiene que recibir un array de array). Grosero error el de "alumnnos" y el bucle for estaba mal escrito. Las 2 primeras soluciones funcionaron perfecto, salvo un detalle, me decía que había como un exceso de "ifs" en la función seAbre. La tercera si funcionó sin problemas!

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios problemas en tu código.

En la función `seAbre` tienes un argumento con nombre `alumnnos` en lugar de `alumnos`: te sobra una "n".

Según el enunciado y los ejemplos de las pruebas, la función `seAbre` no recibe un array de arrays, si no un único array con los retrasos de un día. No hace falta realizar los dos bucles anidados, simplemente tienes que recorrer el array recibido viendo qué elementos son menores o igual a 0.

Igualmente el valor devuelto de esta función no debe ser un array, si no un valor booleano (`true` o `false`) indicando si había suficientes alumnos.

En el primer bucle `for` tomas como valor de finalización `ingresos[i].length`, en lugar de `ingresos.length`.

La segunda función `aperturas` sí que devuelve los valores esperados.

```js
function seAbre(ingresos, alumnos) {
  var alumnosTemprano = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ingresos.length; i++) {
    if (ingresos[i] <= 0) {
      alumnosTemprano++
    }
  }
  
  if (alumnosTemprano >= alumnos) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return abre;
}

function aperturas(array, alumnos) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var alumnosLlegada = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] <=0) {
        alumnosLlegada++
      }
    }
    if (alumnosLlegada >= alumnos) {
      resultado.push(true)
    } else {
      resultado.push(false)
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}

console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 4));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 3));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 2));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 1));
console.log(seAbre([0, 0, 3, 0], 3));
console.log(aperturas([[0,0,3,0],[1,2,4,5],[0,0,-1]],3));
console.log(aperturas([[0,0,-3,0],[1,2,4,5],[0,0,-1]],4));
```

Este problema podría resolverse también utilizando la función `seAbre` desde `aperturas`:

```js
function seAbre(ingresos, alumnos) {
  var alumnosTemprano = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ingresos.length; i++) {
    if (ingresos[i] <= 0) {
      alumnosTemprano++
    }
  }
  
  if (alumnosTemprano >= alumnos) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return abre;
}

function aperturas(array, alumnos) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    resultado.push(seAbre(array[i], alumnos));
  }
  return resultado;
}

console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 4));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 3));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 2));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 1));
console.log(seAbre([0, 0, 3, 0], 3));
console.log(aperturas([[0,0,3,0],[1,2,4,5],[0,0,-1]],3));
console.log(aperturas([[0,0,-3,0],[1,2,4,5],[0,0,-1]],4));
```

Y un último ejemplo utilizando los métodos `filter` y `map` del objeto `Array`:

```js
var seAbre = (ingresos, alumnos) => 
  (ingresos.filter(x => x<=0).length >= alumnos);

var aperturas = (ingresos, alumnos) =>
  ingresos.map(i => seAbre(i, alumnos));

console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 4));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 3));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 2));
console.log(seAbre([10, -5, 3, 0], 1));
console.log(seAbre([0, 0, 3, 0], 3));
console.log(aperturas([[0,0,3,0],[1,2,4,5],[0,0,-1]],3));
console.log(aperturas([[0,0,-3,0],[1,2,4,5],[0,0,-1]],4));
```